# Getting errors while compiling Clewn

Tags: c, debugging, vim, clewn

My environment:

- OS: OSX ML 10.8.5
- VIM: 7.4
- GCC: 4.2.1 (Apple LLVM version 5.0)
- GDB: GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815

I want to debugging in VIM with C programming language. After I seached Google, I found Clewn, but when I `make` it, it returned the following messages.

```
make  all-recursive
Making all in .
gcc -DHAVE_CLEWN  -g -O2 -Wall   -o clewn  clewn.o gdb_lvl2.o gdb_lvl3.o misc.o netbeans.o obstack.o pty.o  -lreadline -lcurses 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ding", referenced from:
      _clewn_beep in misc.o
  "_rl_getc", referenced from:
      _cli_getc in clewn.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [clewn] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Excuse for my English, hope you know what I means. And thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used *clewn* since around 2007–2008 and never on OS X, but you could try the following to at least get it to compile.

> "_ding", referenced from:
>        _clewn_beep in misc.o

Simply comment out the body of the `clewn_beep` function. At least for now.

> "_rl_getc", referenced from:
>        _cli_getc in clewn.o

Try replacing the call to `rl_getc` in `clewn.c` with a call to `cli_getc` and see if that works.

I also had to add the following line in `clewn.c` to get it to compile (OS X 10.8.5):

```
extern int rl_done;
```

Comment: Thanks your answer, I turned to Xcode finally! Thanks again!!